# NLog used into powershell

Tags: powershell, nlog

I developed a pretty long ps1 script(s) and I decided to move from Write-* to use Nlog for logging.
It is working great, but than I realized that I wanted to preserve the writing in the console, since it is more friendly if I'm not trobuleshooting.
So I added a new target, (tried both [ConsoleTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Console-target) and [ColoredConsoleTarget](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ColoredConsole-target)) to see what I was seeing before moving to NLog.
Unfortunately I saw nothing.

This is my NLog.config (that work perfectly for the file target):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">
  <targets async="true">
    <!-- text file - absolute directory e.g. not using "basedir" variable -->
    <target name="logfile"
            xsi:type="File"
            fileName="C:\logfile.txt"
            layout="${longdate}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"/>
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole"
          name="ColoredConsole"
          layout="${longdate}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
          useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="true"
          errorStream="true"
          detectConsoleAvailable="true"
          detectOutputRedirected="true" />
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <!-- log only info and above -->
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="logfile"/>
    <logger name="*" minLevel="Trace" writeTo="ColoredConsole"/>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Once I launch my script (with a batch in this case), the logfile works great, but the console stays empty.

[image]

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.
The version I'm running of NLog is the 4.5.4.
One attribute I was using (detectOutputRedirected) is supported only >= 4.6.

Mistery solved!

Comment: You might consider marking this answer as the solution...